# Custom Authentication with SSRS 2019

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to implement custom forms authentication with SSRS 2016.

I tried this two solutions but no one did the job :

https://estradaci.com/ssrs-custom-authentication-part-1/

https://medium.com/@Estradaci/ssrs-custom-identification-efbb1280e22d

i get always this error : rsServerConfigurationError

Does anyone know where I can find updated procedures for establishing custom authentication?

And Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample
Not sure if you are trying to use ssrs 2019 or 2016 but that link should cover both versions